# GoogleTagManager warning: Unexpected type in Builder: (null)

Tags: ios, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using GoogleTagManager to implement enhanced e-commerce (Google Analytics)
I tried pushing the below dataLayer to GTM.

```
 [dataLayer push:@{@"event",@"purchase",
                @"ecommerce": @{
                @"purchase": @{
                  @"actionField": @{
                    @"id": @"T12345",                         // Transaction ID. Required for purchases and refunds.
                    @"affiliation": @"Online Store",
                    @"revenue": @"35.43",                     // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping)
                    @"tax":"4.90",
                    @"shipping": @"5.99",
                    @"coupon": @"SUMMER_SALE"},
                  @"products": @[                             // List of productFieldObjects.
                    @{@"name": @"Triblend Android T-Shirt",   // Name or ID is required.
                      @"id": @"12345",
                      @"price": @"15.25",
                      @"brand": @"Google",
                      @"category": @"Apparel",
                      @"variant": @"Gray",
                      @"quantity": @1,
                      @"coupon": @""},                        // Optional fields may be omitted or set to empty string.
                    @{@"name": @"Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt",
                      @"id": @"67890",
                      @"price": @"33.75",
                      @"brand": @"Google",
                      @"category": @"Apparel",
                      @"variant": @"Black",
                      @"quantity": @1}]}}}];
```

This is the sample data from Google Tag manager tutorial.
However I get the following warning message when trying to send hits to Google.

```
GoogleTagManager warning: Unexpected type in Builder: (null)
```

The data type I am using is NSNumber (price[doube],revenue[double] & quantity[int]) & NSString for others.

The above data-types work proper for other Ecommerce tags like "AddToCart","Checkout" etc.. however "Purchase" isn't working..

Can any one suggest what else can be tried?

Comment: I see a typo on the first line: `[dataLayer push:@{@"event",@"purchase"`
should probably be: `[dataLayer push:@{@"event":@"purchase"`. But I guess you have the colon there in your code, otherwise the compiler would have complained.

Comment: Not working for me :(

Answer (score 2):

i ran into this problem a while back. it looks to me like a conflict with the previous ecommerce stuff.

before u send the purchase event, try clearing the ecommerce object

```
[self.tagDataLayer push:@{@"ecommerce":[NSNull null]}];
```

this worked out for me